# Drupal 7 file permissions

Tags: linux, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I've been having a problem using views to create thumbnails in drupal 7. Whenever I make (or update) my image styles, the folder which contains them reverts to 0700. Since I'm using suphp  in apache, I keep getting 403's when trying to load the images. Is there a configuration that I'm missing so that I can make folders stay 755 and files 644?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the following suPHP settings are set to true

```
allow_directory_group_writeable
allow_directory_others_writeable
```

Adding the following to `sites/default/settings.php` should prevent the problem reocurring

```
umask(022);
```